# STM32L562 interrupts not working

Tags: stm32, interrupts

I'm programming an STM32L562 (self made PCB), and when i try to init a TIM16 interrupt,

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);
```

using this function, it get stuck at dissembly.

```
0bf977cd:   b.w     0xbf977cc
```

Always at this line.

Same thing happens when i use HAL_Delay() function, it also gets stuck, but in this while cycle

```
while ((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) < wait)
{
}
```

I have looked at my vector table and as far as i can see it has all the interrupts defined.

Here is my code.

```
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint16_t value = 0;
double voltage = 0;

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    //uint16_t timer_val;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_1_GPIO_Port, LED_1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_2_GPIO_Port, LED_2_Pin);


  // Start timer

  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);


    // Get current time (microseconds)

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */


      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1); // This works
      value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      voltage = value*0.0008056;
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = RCC_MSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 8000-1;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 10000-1;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM16_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 2 */

}
```

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  // Check which version of the timer triggered this callback and toggle LED
  if (htim == &htim16 )
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_1_GPIO_Port, LED_1_Pin);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_2_GPIO_Port, LED_2_Pin);
  }
}
```

If you need more info please let me know.

I would appreciate any suggestions i can try, becuse atm im clueless what is wrong.

Comment: Are "tickstart" and "wait" variables? I don't see they declared if so, which type of variables, what's incrementing them, etc. Please enter the full code that is getting you stuck.

Comment: Getting stuck at a `HAL_Delay()` means your SysTick time is not running, or its interrupt is not enabled.

Comment: Can you include your timer configuration code and period elapsed callback implementation?

Comment: @Gimenez tickstart and wait are the variables that are used in the Hal_delay() code, not something i wrote. So if i need to include all the code, then i need to include all the Hal librarys.

Comment: @brahans I have read something like that before, but all the solutions didint work for me. And that also doesnt explain, why just TIM 16 interrupt isnt working. ( I have it enabled in NVIC)

Comment: @mooshoomatt Eddited my main code to add timer configuration, and period elapsed callback to :)

Comment: @JustVan It looks like you are enabling the interrupt manually in the timer init function. I am not super familiar with STMCube's auto-generated code. Are you sure that NVIC_EnableIRQ is the correct substitute for enabling the interrupt in the IOC? Maybe try enabling the IRQ in the IOC and removing your call to NVIC_EnableIRQ...